# How to vectorize and speed-up double for-loop for pandas dataframe when doing text similarity scoring

Tags: python, pandas, similarity, fuzzy-classification

I have the following dataframe:

```
d_test = {
    'name' : ['South Beach', 'Dog', 'Bird', 'Ant', 'Big Dog', 'Beach', 'Dear', 'Cat', 'Fish', 'Dry Fish'],
    'cluster_number' : [1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1, 4, 2, 2, 2]
}
df_test = pd.DataFrame(d_test)
```

I want to identify similar names in `name` column if those names belong to one cluster number and create unique id for them. For example `South Beach` and `Beach` belong to cluster number `1` and their similarity score is pretty high. So we associate it with unique id, say `1`. Next cluster is number `2` and three entities from `name` column belong to this cluster: `Dog`, `Big Dog`, `Cat`, 'Fish' and 'Dry Fish'. `Dog` and `Big Dog` have high similarity score and their unique id will be, say `2`. For `Cat` unique id will be, say `3`. Finally for 'Fish' and 'Dry Fish' unique id will be, say `4`. And so on.

I created a code for the logic above:

```
# pip install thefuzz
from thefuzz import fuzz

df_test = df_test.sort_values(['cluster_number', 'name'])
df_test.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

df_test['id'] = 0

i = 1
for index, row in df_test.iterrows():
    row_ = row
    index_ = index

    while index_ < len(df_test) and df_test.loc[index, 'cluster_number'] == df_test.loc[index_, 'cluster_number'] and df_test.loc[index_, 'id'] == 0:
        if row['name'] == df_test.loc[index_, 'name'] or fuzz.ratio(row['name'], df_test.loc[index_, 'name']) > 50:
            df_test.loc[index_,'id'] = i
            is_i_used = True
        index_ += 1

    if is_i_used == True:
        i += 1
        is_i_used = False
```

Code generates expected result:

```
    name         cluster_number  id
0   Beach               1        1
1   South Beach         1        1
2   Big Dog             2        2
3   Cat                 2        3
4   Dog                 2        2
5   Dry Fish            2        4
6   Fish                2        4
7   Ant                 3        5
8   Bird                3        6
9   Dear                4        7
```

Computation runs for 210 seconds for dataframe with 1 million rows where in average each cluster has about 10 rows and max cluster size is about 200 rows. I am trying to understand how to vectorize the code.

Also `thefuzz` module has `process` function and it allows to process data at once:

```
from thefuzz import process
out = process.extract("Beach", df_test['name'], limit=len(df_test))
```

But I don't see if it can help with speeding up the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic problem here is that Pandas is very slow compared to NumPy in many operations like indexing.

I rewrote this part of code:

```
for index, row in df_test.iterrows():
row_ = row
index_ = index

while index_ < len(df_test) and df_test.loc[index, 'cluster_number'] == df_test.loc[index_, 'cluster_number'] and df_test.loc[index_, 'id'] == 0:
    if row['name'] == df_test.loc[index_, 'name'] or fuzz.ratio(row['name'], df_test.loc[index_, 'name']) > 50:
        df_test.loc[index_,'id'] = i
        is_i_used = True
    index_ += 1

if is_i_used == True:   # why to ask whether a bool is True? ;)
    i += 1
    is_i_used = False
```

To such a form:

```
cluster_number = df_test.cluster_number.values
did = df_test.id.values
names = df_test.name.values
len_df = len(df_test)

for index, name in enumerate( df_test.name.values ):
    index_ = index

    while index_ < len_df and cluster_number[index] == cluster_number[index_] and did[index_] == 0:
        name_condition = names[index_]
        if name == name_condition or fuzz.ratio(name, name_condition) > 50:
            did[index_] = I
            is_i_used = True
        index_ += 1

    if is_i_used:
        i += 1
        is_i_used = False
```

Basically, I transformed pandas code to simple numpy code and it appears it speeds up 100x times for a 100_000-rows data frame. I know that it's an old issue, but it was raised by a community bot. I hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

The code is so slow because there is there are nested loops (i.e., runtime complexity is O(n²)).

One way to get remove the inner loop is to hash previously seen answers. Instead of iterating through each row a second time and performing a conditional check, perform a set membership check (i.e., runtime complexity of O(1)).

Additionally, pandas is inherently slower for computation than other options in Python. Switching to NumPy and/or Numba will speed up the code.

Comment: I updated the code with `while loop` instead of `for loop`. Now time complexity is `O(n*max_cluster_size)`.  It is still too slow for my task.

Comment: Do not loop (while or for). Look up the answer in a precomputed data structure, like a set.

Comment: NumPy and Numba are only viable for certain text sim metrics, and require the data be preprocessed beforehand in place or on load, which isn't a bad thing but is a consideration

Answer (score 0):

Frame challenge:

Text similarity does not scale nicely, and vectorizing will not yield the performance increases you need here. The specific approach I reach for when I need to scale up text similarity is a pre-clustering step using cheap calculations and saving the expensive text similarity calculations for items within the same pre-cluster. Pre-clustering technique chosen depends on document type and length, for example for shorter natural language strings like names you could build a hashmap of {name_token: {name_ids_containing_token}}, whereas for longer natural language documents something like minhash may be more appropriate.